# Mail Like Selection IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This seems simple in theory but i cant seem to find the right solution.

I am trying to achieve a UITableViewCell that once selected will navigate to a detail view but ALSO turn grey. Once navigating back that item will stay grey until deleted from the datasource.

I am able to get it to change colors once being selected but on navigation back into the UITableView it no longer keeps the color.

Here is my code in a custom UITableViewCell Class:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
if(selected) {
    [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
} else {
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
}
```

I feel my logic is correct though i cant put my finger on what i am missing to achieve my end result.

Comment: Is the tableview reloading when you navigate back to the view that contains it?

Comment: Can you show code about cellForRowAtIndexPath method?